# Overwriting generic type in method

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a base class like this:

```
class FooClass {
  getFoo<FooType extends string | number>(foo: FooType): string {
    throw "not implemented";
  }
}
```

And I want to have 2 child classes extend from it. I tried the following:

```
class NumberFooClass extends FooClass {
  getFoo(foo: number): string {
    return "" + foo;
  }
}

class StringFooClass extends FooClass {
  getFoo(foo: string): string {
    return foo;
  }
}
```

But I get a typescript error for both these. Here is the one for the number class:

```
Property 'getFoo' in type 'NumberFooClass' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'FooClass'.
  Type '(foo: number) => string' is not assignable to type '<FooType extends string | number>(foo: FooType) => string'.
    Types of parameters 'foo' and 'foo' are incompatible.
      Type 'FooType' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2416)
```

I thought I could maybe do

```
class NumberFooClass extends FooClass {
  getFoo<number>(foo: number): string {
    return "" + foo;
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work either; I get the error:

```
'number' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Type parameter name cannot be 'number'.
```

How can I narrow down the variable type in the child classes?

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't (safely). Imagine that you have a function that takes any `FooClass` and it passes strings or numbers to it, like the signature describes. You give it a `NumberFooClass`, and your code breaks, because your `NumberFooClass` doesn't handle strings correctly. Even worse, you don't know why, because if TypeScript allowed this, it would not have given any compiler errors. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll mull this over more and figure out what I should actually be doing here